# Print functions on Python

Tags: python

I'm starting to learn this language and so far so good. But I had one problem I hope anyone can help me with. I'm trying to print my function, but python is telling me that "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable". Here is my code

```
def far2Cent(num):
   return "Tu nuevo número es" ((num-32)/(1.8))

num =int(input("Ingresa un número que quieras convertir: "))
far2Cent(num)
```

Comment: change `"Tu nuevo número es" ((num-32)/(1.8))` to `"Tu nuevo número es {}".format((num-32)/1.8)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `return` line:

`return "Tu nuevo número es {}".format((num-32)/(1.8))`

To print the result, you'll also need:

`print(far2Cent(num))`

Answer (score 0):

```
def far2Cent(num):
   return "Tu nuevo número es" + str((num-32)/(1.8))

num =int(input("Ingresa un número que quieras convertir: "))
print(far2Cent(num))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
"Tu nuevo número es" ((num-32)/(1.8))
```

I don’t know from what language this comes from, but this is not valid in python, if you need to format a string to put a number, use format:

```
"Tu nuevo número es {}".format((num-32)/1.8)
```